# react-hooks/exhaustive-deps warning

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I use react hook **useEffect** like the following code for fetching data and changing state in it. For avoiding the infinite loop I add an empty array as the second parameter of the useEffect and I get this warning. Do I just ignore it or I have to fix it? If so, how can fix it? I just want the componentDidMount effect here.
I appreciate any idea?

```
useEffect(() => {
 fetch('/login')
 .then(response => {
   if (response.ok) fetchAll() 
   else setLoading({ ...loading, signin: true, progress:false });     
 }).catch(() =>{
   setLoading({ ...loading, signin: true, progress:false });
 })
},[]);
```

Comment: What is a warning of you get? Can you provide all code to replicate?

Comment: Maybe this is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook

Comment: This is what I get
`React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'fetchAll' and 'loading'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'setLoading(l => ...)' if you only need 'loading' in the 'setLoading' call  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` @PiotrŻak

Comment: try pass to the useEffect fetchAll & loading

Comment: useEffect((fetchAll, loading) => {

Comment: It causes an infinite loop if I pass the missing dependencies to the array

Comment: I saw this post, but cannot solve my problem @norbitrial

Comment: @Fardin not to the array, pass to the function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205963/discussion-between-piotr-zak-and-fardin2689).

Answer (score 0):

try this, this should fix the warning

```
useEffect(() => {
 fetch('/login')
 .then(response => {
   if (response.ok) fetchAll() 
   else setLoading(loading => ({ ...loading, signin: true, progress:false }));     
 }).catch(() =>{
   setLoading(loading => ({ ...loading, signin: true, progress:false }));
 })
},[]);
```